# Chaining Bayes rule

Tags: probability

We know from Bayes rule that

$$
P(A|B) = \frac{P(B|A)P(A)}{P(B)}
$$

but how do I find

$$
P(A|B, C)
$$
i.e. Probability of $A$ happening given that $B$ and $C$ have happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple different ways to do this, depending on how much data you have at your disposal.

For starters, you could do the obvious: the event that you describe as "$B,C$" is really the event that both $B$ and $C$ occur... that is, $B\cap C$. So, you have (by treating $B\cap C$ as an event in its own right)
$$
P(A\mid B,C)=\frac{P(A,B,C)}{P(B,C)}.
$$

Of course, if you'd like to do some more intermediate things, you can use
$$
P(A\mid B,C)=\frac{P(A, B\mid C)}{P(B\mid C)}.
$$
(You can verify this directly using the conditional probability formula.) You *could* apply Bayes' rule to the numerator and denominator here, but you'll just get back the previous formula after cancellation (as long as no division by $0$ happens).

Switching the roles of $B$ and $C$ also works.

At the end of the day: there's something of an art to deciding how to break down such a formula.  It will really depend on what information you either have or have easy access to.